# Find MIN date associated with FIRST non-0 value

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to generate a list of manager start dates which can be determined by the minimum `AS_OF` date which is the table partition.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in a non-processing heavy manner. I believe there are some windows functions that can are better suited to accomplish this.

I do have the below which works, but is terribly slow.

```
SELECT
    Employee_ID,
    MIN(As_Of) as manager_start_date
FROM table
WHERE Direct_Reports > 0
GROUP BY 1
```

Sample table below with desired output at bottom.

---

```
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| Employee_ID | Direct_Reports | As_Of    |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 1           | 0              | 1/1/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 1           | 0              | 1/2/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 1           | 0              | 1/3/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 1           | 1              | 1/4/2019 |  '<--- First non 0 value for Employee 1'
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 2           | 0              | 1/1/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 2           | 0              | 1/2/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 2           | 5              | 1/3/2019 |  '<--- First non 0 value for Employee 2'
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 3           | 0              | 1/1/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 3           | 0              | 1/2/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 3           | 5              | 1/3/2019 |  '<--- First non 0 value for Employee 3'
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 3           | 10             | 1/4/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
| 3           | 7              | 1/5/2019 |
+-------------+----------------+----------+
```

---

```
+-------------+--------------------+
| Employee_ID | Manager_Start_Date |
+-------------+--------------------+
| 1           | 1/4/2019           |
+-------------+--------------------+
| 2           | 1/3/2019           |
+-------------+--------------------+
| 3           | 1/3/2019           |
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select empid , min(case when directreport > 0 then as_of END) from dbo.manager
group by empid
```

Comment: Why do you think this woulb be faster?